# project Euler #13 c++

Tags: c++

https://projecteuler.net/problem=13

> Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.

I try to solve it using C++ in Xcode. I saved the numbers in a file and built it successfully but got the wrong answer. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  double sum = 1;
  double num;
  ifstream fin("/Users/pwd/programs/projectEuler13/num.txt");

  while (fin) {
    fin >> num;
    sum += num;
  }
    fin.close();
  cout.precision(12);
  cout << sum << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I got the result:
5.59087976462e+51

So first 10 digits of the sum: 5590879764.
But it is wrong. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: double? And *you* need to cut it down to 10 digits.

Comment: Uh, what part is wrong? Maybe I don't understand the question. It asks you for the first 10 digits of the sum. You got 5.59087976462e+51 as the sum. What are the first 10 digits of that?

Comment: @CodyGray Isn't that scientific notation?

Comment: Hint: how do you add a whole bunch of numbers by hand, on paper? (This is very close to being a trick question - you only need to remember what you did in primary school and think slightly outside the box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues I can see:

1. Starting the sum from 1, although this is highly unlikely to change your result.
2. Using floating-point introduces inaccuracies. More likely to change your result but in this case it probably still won't, because you only need 10 significant digits.
3. The most serious problem: Incorrectly looping over the input. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). This will probably cause you to add the last number twice. The correct way to loop over an input stream is:

   ```
   while (fin >> val) {
        //do something with val.
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah you are right, but in this case how can I avoid floating point?

Comment: You can use a big-number library like GMP, or implement long-addition yourself by representing each number as an array of digits. But in this case floating point is probably good enough.

Comment: It does give the correct answer to enough significant digits to solve the probelm, given the fix in #3.